# message - (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action code - 200 in java

Tags: java, facebook

I am trying to access facebook api in simple java project.
I have tried following code :

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
        try {
            System.out.println("oauth start");
            facebook.setOAuthAppId("", "");

            String accessTokenString = "EAACEdEose0cBAE7Vw50TIXg0tSkux6LBFeynh7FNZByV8uAYrtIKZAf0YYgMoAwaU4cJZChoYMmbytRUnKUc0bVgMC5z8bWo0Jh0yfEZALSHk2eZAB9fCMcWZCWTYVbZCt5ZBDZBgD6Kmfduo8DbX35ma1XMpdnK7sQhizOgQ8jplZAVjtdZBDZAgcC4";

            AccessToken at = new AccessToken(accessTokenString);

            facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(at);
            System.out.println("oauth start");

            facebook.postStatusMessage("Hello World from Facebook4J.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occurred "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

But getting following error message :

> message - (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform
>   this action code - 200

How to resolve to it  now .

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You haven't authorized the application to post status messages.

Comment: So what to do now for authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give (in Facebook) the required authorizations for your application. Otherwise you (as in you the application) aren't allowed to do anything, since it could be potentially harmful.

Comment: how to do authorization ?

Comment: See the APPS part of your Facebook.